# I want to control a flash video (swf) playing automatically

Tags: flash

I wrote a flash  video on HTML and play it, 
I want to do it for beginning setting after pushing the start button .

```
<object width="***" height="***" align="middle" id="player" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"> 
<param value="sameDomain" name="allowScriptAccess" />
<param value="***.swf" name="movie" />
<param value="false" name="autoplay" />
<param value="false" name="controller" />
<param value="high" name="quality" />
<param value="#ff0000" name="bgcolor" /> <embed width="600" height="440" align="middle" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" name="player" quality="high" menu="false" autoplaye="false" loop="false" src="***.swf"></embed> </object>
```

So,I add this code

but it is play automatically.

What's wrong?

How to do it ?

Comment: Controlling the player is done inside the flash movie using the actionscript code, not the html.

Answer (score 0):

If you have source of player you can add flashVars detection and create your own param to set if video should play or not.

Answer (score 0):

The autoplay parameter you are setting false is for the container swf NOT the internal video player.

As @Konrad said you'll need to adjust the player in the fla OR set flashVars to disable autoplay.

```
 <param name="flashvars"   
    value='config={"clip":{"url":"video.flv","autoPlay":false}}' />
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Konrad and @discorax said, you can look for a specific flashvar if you have control over the flash element.

Additionally, Flash videos can also expose methods that can be called by JavaScript to interact with them.  If you've created the Flash, you could create such an interface to have more flexibility and control (if necessary for the project).